# Set default value extracted from mysql database for dropdown list php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a php page that asks the user to enter his birth date from 3 dropdown lists(one for year, one for month, one for day), then, I store these values in mysql database in one date variable as follow:

```
  $date= $BirthYear.'-'.$BirthMonth.'-'.$BirthDay;
```

now, I have another php form that let the user edit his information but the problem is: how to set the default values for the three drop down lists in the edit form to the stored date values?
I fetch the date values from database as following:

```
  $DOB_Y= $row['YEAR(BirthDate)'];
    $DOB_M= $row['MONTH(BirthDate)'];
    $DOB_D= $row['DAY(BirthDate)'];
```

My dropdown list code for birth DAY is:

```
 <select id="form_dob_day" name="dob_day"  class = "option" required >
    <?php 
    for($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
    {
    echo "<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

and the same for MONTH and YEAR.

I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
<select id="form_dob_day" name="dob_day"  class = "option" required >
    <?php 
for($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
{


 echo "<option value=".$i. if ($DOB_D==$i) echo "selected" ">".$i."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: "It doesn't work" is **always** a useless thing to say unless you are going to provide the error message (if any) or compare the desired outcome/output with the actual outcome/output. The better the question the better then answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your syntax, this should correct it:

```
<select id="form_dob_day" name="dob_day"  class = "option" required >
<?php 
    for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '" ' . (($DOB_D == $i) ? "selected"  : '') . '>' . $i . '</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you, I tried it but it doesn't select the value :(

Comment: Strange. Did you check that $DOB_D contains the right value?

Comment: I just want to suggest an alternative syntax: `(['', 'selected'][$DOB_D == $i])` for `(($DOB_D == $i) ? "selected"  : '')`

Comment: This is really great @sensorario, simple and brief. Thank you :)